# The Odin Project - Project Ruby: Translating from English to Pig Latin

Tags: ruby, pig-latin

I just finished the pig latin translator for The Odin Project and I would appreciate some honest feedback for my code. The code is intended to be "test-driven learning", and therefore emulates test driven development.

Here is the prompt:

Pig Latin is a made-up children's language that's intended to be confusing. It obeys a few simple rules (below) but when it's spoken quickly it's really difficult for non-children (and non-native speakers) to understand.

Rule 1: If a word begins with a vowel sound, add an "ay" sound to the end of the word.

Rule 2: If a word begins with a consonant sound, move it to the end of the word, and then add an "ay" sound to the end of the word.

(There are a few more rules for edge cases, and there are regional variants too, but that should be enough to understand the tests.)

Here is the test spec:

```
require "pig_latin"

describe "#translate" do

  it "translates a word beginning with a vowel" do
    s = translate("apple")
    expect(s).to eq("appleay")
  end

  it "translates a word beginning with a consonant" do
    s = translate("banana")
    expect(s).to eq("ananabay")
  end

  it "translates a word beginning with two consonants" do
    s = translate("cherry")
    expect(s).to eq("errychay")
  end

  it "translates two words" do
    s = translate("eat pie")
    expect(s).to eq("eatay iepay")
  end

  it "translates a word beginning with three consonants" do
    expect(translate("three")).to eq("eethray")
  end

  it "counts 'sch' as a single phoneme" do
    s = translate("school")
    expect(s).to eq("oolschay")
  end

  it "counts 'qu' as a single phoneme" do
    s = translate("quiet")
    expect(s).to eq("ietquay")
  end

  it "counts 'qu' as a consonant even when it's preceded by a consonant" do
    s = translate("square")
    expect(s).to eq("aresquay")
  end

  it "translates many words" do
    s = translate("the quick brown fox")
    expect(s).to eq("ethay ickquay ownbray oxfay")
  end

  # Test-driving bonus:
  # * write a test asserting that capitalized words are still capitalized (but with a different initial capital letter, of course)
  # * retain the punctuation from the original phrase

end
```

Finally, here is my code:

```
def translate(phrase) #translates individual words or multiple words into pig latin
  new_phrase = []
  if phrase.include? " "
    new_phrase = phrase.split(" ").map do |word|
      rearrange(word)
    end
    new_phrase = new_phrase.join(" ")
  else
    new_phrase = rearrange(phrase)
  end
  new_phrase
end

def rearrange(word) #rearranges individual words into pig latin
  vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y"]
  new_word = word
  word.each_char do |char|
    if char == "u" && new_word[-1] == "q"
      new_word << "u"
      new_word.slice!(0)
      next
    elsif vowels.include? char
      new_word << "ay"
      break
    else
      new_word << char
      new_word.slice!(0)
      next
    end
  end
  new_word
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

- `expect(translate("three")).to eq("eethray")`. Be consistent, use always a local variable or don't. I think this way looks pretty cool.
- Isn't the code inside a module/class?
- `translate`. This methods is unnecessarily verbose. You don't need to check if there is a space or not, since the algorithm works just the same if there is not.
- Those two `next`s are redundant.
- `rearrange`: This method would look so much nicer if you don't use imperative style.
- If a regular expression can express the rules, you should consider using it. It will be easier to read and much more compact.
- Side note: The rules are pretty simple. If they ever get more complex, a manual processing will be undecipherable and regexps will come short. Then you'll need something more sophisticated, like a parser (i.e. [grammy](https://github.com/Ragmaanir/grammy)).

I'd write:

```
def translate(phrase)
  phrase.split(" ").map { |word| rearrange(word) }.join(" ") 
end

def rearrange(word)
  match = word.match(/^((?:qu|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])*)(.*)$/)
  match ? match[2] + match[1] + "ay" : word
end
```

If you have trouble reading that regular expressions, consider using multi-line regexps with named captures:

```
def rearrange(word)
  match = word.match(%r{
    ^
    (?<leading_consonants>(?:qu|[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])*) 
    (?<rest>.*)
    $)
  match ? match[:rest] + match[:leading_consonants] + "ay" : word
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I kinda figured that the methods were too verbose, I appreciate the feedback.